# How to set plus symbol inside a circle using content in css for IE

Tags: css

Can anyone help me with css issue as i am not able to set in IE. I am trying to create a circle with plus sign inside it and plus sign should be a bit small in size it should not touch the circle using content in css.            ie.content:" \2295" in css by doing this it creates circle with plus sign inside it but the plus sign touches the circle and i dont want that way . Can anyone guide me how to achieve it in css using content.

Comment: IE 5.5, or IE 6, or IE 7, or IE 8, or IE 9, or IE 10, or IE 11?

Comment: I am trying for IE 11

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this. Also add the code which you have tried.

Comment: I did updated. My code in css is                                                        `folder .gwt-TreeItem .treeMenu .downArrow:after
{
 content: " \2295";
 float: right;
 margin-right: -10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "elegant-icons" !important;
}  `                                                                                                            it helped to create a circle and inside plus sign but the plus sign touches the circle i want it in the plus sign small size

Comment: We need full code including HTML which demonstrates the issue you are having. Adding a Stack Snippet would be a good way of doing this.

Comment: Dunno if i am getting this right, but see my fiddle and tell me if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/mrfybmc3/

Comment: Sorry not using html doing all things in Gwt.

Comment: @Pyere i tried that way but want to implement  using content property in css

Comment: ohhh if I understood right i think you need to choose another code because you cannot seperate the plus sign from the circle in " \2295" it is considered on character

Comment: Yes i tried to find another code for that but alas didnt found any :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do a small research to find the suitable Character for you but couldn't.

So i thought of a way around it:

- Create your SVG Symbol using illustrator
- Create an woff, eot and TTF font from svg using
  https://icomoon.io/app/#/select. (eot to support IE)
- Download the Package and load the character using CSS.

It is impossible to create a fiddle for that but what I did is creating a small demo and upload it to my server where you can see how it works and you can download the source.

This is the Link: http://mummersmile.com/font/font/

Hope this would help you.